# Python - can split() command be indexed?

Tags: python, csv, split

I am trying to parse and split the line:

```
redfish - 12,000 lbs - trade for SNE stocks
```

The code I'm trying is:

```
elif ('-' in line) and ('lbs' in line):
    fish, remainder = line.split('-')               #splits line into two halves at the - (fish to one side)
    #print("line.split is:", line.split(':'))
    if '@' in remainder:
        weight, price = remainder.split('@')        #splits already split piece (remainder) into two halves at @
        if '-->' in price:
            price, junk = price.split('-->')
    if 'trade' in remainder:
        if 'to ' in remainder:
            weight, price = remainder.split('to ')
        elif ' or ' in remainder:
            weight, price = remainder.split(' or ') #add spaces around ' or ' so we don't match 'for'
    if 'swap' in remainder:
        weight, price = remainder.split('to ')
```

It fails on the line:

`fish, remainder = line.split('-')`

with the error:

`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

Now I know this is due to the fact that there are 2 `'-'` in that line and Python doesn't know which one to split on, so I tried telling it to split on the first `'-'` with: `fish, remainder = line.split('-'[0])` but that fails.

So my question is: is there a way around this? Can I index the `split()` command another way so that I can successfully split that line like I want to?

Thanks for any help or tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, try using:

`line.split('-', 1)`

It tells it to split the string only on the first '-' it encounters.

However, I don't know any possibility of directly 'indexing' your split command if you want to split only on the second one.

In that case I'd recommend splitting the whole string and then joining the parts you want.

Comment: Ohh gotcha. I knew it would be a simple answer. Yeah I expect I'll have to split on the second one later when it's in the remainder. Thanks for the answer though :) I'll click the check mark to accept it in a few minutes when it allows me to